# Alignment Produces Unintended Output

Tags: alignment

I am using LaTeX to generate a CV (without a template)

Consider the following MRE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent Coadvisor: Dr. Daniel A. Ashlock \hfill Department of Mathematics and \\ \hfill Statistics

\end{document}
```

When the above is compiled, unintended output is produced.

I would like the word "Statistics" to be positioned at the right margin. Instead it is positioned at he left margin

I tried replacing \hfill with both \flushright and \raggedright to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: `\hfill` needs something "to push against" and there isn't anything at the staty of a line, try `\strut\hfill`

Comment: `\hspace*{\fill}Statistics`